# How do I make my navbar stay to the left side of my homepage?

Tags: html, css

I have a navbar, and as one can see in the jsfiddle, it is placed horizontally at the top of my website, while I would like it to be vertical that goes through the entire website. A visual example of this can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYC0q.jpg). I don't want it to be anything fancy like that example, just a standard vertical rectangle that I can add divs and whatever else I need to add.

HTML

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <nav>
      <div>
        <h1>ll</h1>
        <p>zwerrrrrrss</p>
        <p>werghhh</p>
        <br>
        <p>zdeeeeeu</p>
        <br>
        <p>awer7</p>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <header>
      <div>
        <p>lkwwss</p>
      </div>
    </header>
```

CSS

```
nav {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row-end: 10;
  align-items: right;
  background: #04B4AE;
  color: #F2F2F2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0vw .2vw 0vw .2vw;
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/obs24h61/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly, is this what you need?

you were almost there with your code, you just have to play around bit more and you could've got the answer, use `text-align:left` and if you need give some `height` and `width` for the left nav bar.

I have added few `divs` if that is not an issue, which makes the things cleaner.

```css
#main{
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid yellow;
  display:inline-block;
}
#left{
  width:30%;
  float:left;
  align-items: right;
  background: #04B4AE;
  color: #F2F2F2;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0vw .2vw 0vw .2vw;
  display:inline-block;
  height:500px;
}
#right{
margin-left: 31%;
height:500px;
  border:1px solid red;
  background-color:gray;
}
zznav {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row-end: 10;
  align-items: right;
  background: #04B4AE;
  color: #F2F2F2;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0vw .2vw 0vw .2vw;
  display:inline-block; 
}
```

```html
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <div id="main">
  

  <div id="left">
   <nav>
      <div>
        <h1>ll</h1>
        <p>zwerrrrrrss</p>
        <p>werghhh</p>
        <br>
        <p>zdeeeeeu</p>
        <br>
        <p>awer7</p>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
   <div id="right">
     <header>
      <div>
        <p>lkwwss</p>
      </div>
    </header>
   </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: I am glad I was able to help you, would you mind accept it as answer and voting if you think if it is worth voting? thanks.

Comment: Actually I'm sorry but after reviewing it isn't quite what I wanted. The header block is still underneath the nav bar, while I would like it so the full body of the website is to the right of the nav bar.

Comment: the code you've written is meant to display underneath `nav`, so you need `header` block to move to right side?

Comment: Header and everything else, yes.

Comment: @jkjwwqqq I have updated my code with color codes as well.